# Tailwind class works when passed as prop but doesn't when applied directly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I have this component:

```js
export const TextInput = ({
  label,
  wrapperClassName = "",
  inputClassName = "",
  labelClassName = "",
  placeholder = "",
  ...props
}: InputProps & FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
  const [field, meta] = useField(props);

  return (
    <div className={wrapperClassName}>
      <label
        className={`block mb-2 text-lg font-medium text-dark ${labelClassName}`}
        htmlFor={props.id || props.name}
      >
        {label}
      </label>
      <input
        className={`bg-gray-50 border border-primary text-secondary text-md rounded-lg
        focus:ring-primary p-2 ${inputClassName}`}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        {...field}
      />
      {meta.touched && meta.error ? (
        <div className="error">{meta.error}</div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now focus only on the classNames of the  tag. When I apply the `text-dark` className it doesn't work for some reason and it doesn't appear at all in my devtools styles tab.
If i pass the `text-dark` className via the `labelClassName` prop it works perfectly fine. Can you spot the flaw?

This is my tailwind config file:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        sm: "480px",
        md: "768px",
        lg: "976px",
        xl: "1440px",
      },
      colors: {
        primary: "#FF0000",
        secondary: "#414141",
        dark: "#252525",
        light: "#F9F5EB",
        orange: "#AF0404",
      },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

A funny and weird thing is that the `text-secondary` specifically works in both cases but no other class (even the default tailwind ones) don't work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the file that the component is in is covered by the [`content` file globs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration). The symptoms you describe sound like Tailwind is not scanning the file and thus it does not "see" the class names and thus does not generate the CSS rules that you expect.

Comment: Damn I am so dump, yes it was in a directory which wasn't mentioned in the globs. Thank you so much.